# Delay Startup of Windows Embedded Shell Launcher

Tags: windows, powershell, kiosk-mode

*Updated Query*
 I am trying to setup a user on Windows as a "Kiosk" user. This is so that they are completely locked out from windows features and only have access to one application. I am using the windows embedded shell launcher application to assign what application to run with that user and have so far had success.

The issue I am having is that the application requires license from another piece of software that is set to start on start up, but the shell starts to quickly and the application I want running displays a license error on screen. I need to delay the starting of the shell.

I use a power shell script to set up the shell, but from research, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0d9fc55-ab03-43e7-9c3a-10ce85060386/how-to-custom-shell?forum=quebeccomponentsforum, this script just sets the registry value `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinlogonShell= "something.exe"`.

Therefore on startup even if I put in a `Start-Sleep` delay, or try and work out if the licensing program is up and running first before starting the application, the script is never run on start up as it is using a register.

Is there a way to delay the starting of this shell, or delay running this register on start up? I have added the scrip below that I am using to set up the shells and the links that I have based the code off
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-shelllauncher

```
     #----- Function to Check if shell launcher license is enabled ------#
    function Check-ShellLauncherLicenseEnabled
    {
        [string]$source = @"
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    static class CheckShellLauncherLicense
    {
        const int S_OK = 0;

        public static bool IsShellLauncherLicenseEnabled()
        {
            int enabled = 0;

            if (NativeMethods.SLGetWindowsInformationDWORD("EmbeddedFeature-ShellLauncher-Enabled", out enabled) != S_OK) {
                enabled = 0;
            }
            return (enabled != 0);
        }

        static class NativeMethods
        {
            [DllImport("Slc.dll")]
            internal static extern int SLGetWindowsInformationDWORD([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string valueName, out int value);
        }

    }
    "@

        $type = Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source -PassThru

        return $type[0]::IsShellLauncherLicenseEnabled()
    }

    [bool]$result = $false

    $result = Check-ShellLauncherLicenseEnabled
    "`nShell Launcher license enabled is set to " + $result
    if (-not($result))
    {
        "`nThis device doesn&#39;t have required license to use Shell Launcher"
        exit
    }

    $COMPUTER = "localhost"
    $NAMESPACE = "root\standardcimv2\embedded"

    # Create a handle to the class instance so we can call the static methods.
    try {
        $ShellLauncherClass = [wmiclass]"\\$COMPUTER\${NAMESPACE}:WESL_UserSetting"
        } catch [Exception] {
        write-host $_.Exception.Message; 
        write-host "Make sure Shell Launcher feature is enabled"
        exit
        }


    #-----Function to retrieve the SID for the user account on the machine-----#

    function Get-UsernameSID($AccountName) {

        $NTUserObject = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($AccountName)
        $NTUserSID = $NTUserObject.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

        return $NTUserSID.Value
    }

    #---- Get the SID's for accounts-----# 

    $Operator_SID = Get-UsernameSID("Operator")
    $Admin_SID = Get-UsernameSID("Administrator")

    #----- Define actions to take when the shell program exits -----#

    $restart_shell = 0
    $restart_device = 1
    $shutdown_device = 2


    #----- Set Default Shell ----#
    # This example sets the command prompt as the default shell, and restarts the device if the command prompt is closed. 

    # $ShellLauncherClass.SetDefaultShell("cmd.exe", $restart_device)

    #----- Default Shell Display -----#
    # Display the default shell to verify that it was added correctly.

    $DefaultShellObject = $ShellLauncherClass.GetDefaultShell()

    "`nDefault Shell is set to " + $DefaultShellObject.Shell + " and the default action is set to " + $DefaultShellObject.defaultaction

    # ----- Operator Shell Set -----#
     $ShellLauncherClass.SetCustomShell($Operator_SID, "C:\Components\application.exe", ($null), ($null), $restart_shell)       
   # ----- Admin Shell Set -----#
    # Set Explorer as the shell for administrator.

     $ShellLauncherClass.SetCustomShell($Admin_SID, "explorer.exe")

    #-----Enable the Shell Launcher -----#

    $ShellLauncherClass.SetEnabled($TRUE)

    $IsShellLauncherEnabled = $ShellLauncherClass.IsEnabled()

    "`nEnabled is set to " + $IsShellLauncherEnabled.Enabled

    #-----Remove Custom Shell -----#
    # To remove a user shell, comment out the $ShelllauncherClass.SetCustomShell command and uncomment the required RemoveCustomShell command

    # $ShellLauncherClass.RemoveCustomShell($Admin_SID)

    # $ShellLauncherClass.RemoveCustomShell($Operator_SID)

    #----- Disable Shell Launcher -----# Uncomment to use

    # $ShellLauncherClass.SetEnabled($FALSE)

    # $IsShellLauncherEnabled = $ShellLauncherClass.IsEnabled()

    # "`nEnabled is set to " + $IsShellLauncherEnabled.Enabled

    #----- Display all the custom shells defined -----#

    "`nCurrent settings for custom shells:"
    Get-WmiObject -namespace $NAMESPACE -computer $COMPUTER -class WESL_UserSetting | Select Sid, Shell, DefaultAction
```

Comment: when i start a script that has `Start-Sleep` as the 1st command ... it the remainder of the script is on hold until the cmdlet reaches its timeout.

Comment: So are you suggesting putting Start-Sleep right at the beginning of the script to delay its execution on startup?

Comment: What does _startup_ refer to? Something that runs when the user logs on? Or startup of a script on demand? As @Lee_Dailey notes, `Start-Sleep` by design waits _synchronously_ for the specified number of seconds before continuing execution. Since you say "it just delays" yet that is what `Start-Sleep` is designed to do, please clarify your requirements by _directly updating your question_ (don't use comments). Generally, it's better not to rely on a fixed delay, but instead to (periodically) test if the desired states has been reached.

Comment: @ConfusedDuck - yes, putting the cmdlet right at the start will delay the entire script. i use it in several scripts to pause the script so that a msg can be read - a 30 second pause is enuf to allow reading a simple msg.

Answer (score 1):

A much more sophisticated option would be to check that the process you're waiting for has started.

If it's running on the same box, then use `Get-Process` to see if it's up. Or `Get-NetTCPConnection` if it starts listening on a specific port (if the license server is accessed from across the LAN, then that's the option you'd choose).

```
do {
    sleep 10 
    $proc = Get-Process -Name licsrv -ea silentlycontinue
} until ($proc)

Start-process ...
```

You might want to have a loop counter in there as well so that you can do X loops and escape if it's taking too long.

```
$loop = 0
do {
    sleep 10 
    $proc = Get-Process -Name licsrv -ea silentlycontinue
    $loop++
} until ($proc -or $loop -ge 60) #wait until proc runs or 10 mins
If ($proc) {Start-process ... } # the process is running, not loop termination
Else {Throw "some error message"}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a very similar issue that I managed to resolve yesterday after finding your post.

We're using the shell launcher for a VDI kiosk but were running into an issue where the launcher would launch the VMware Horizon View Client before the network established a connection and it would fail with the message  "Couldn't resolve host name".

I modified the shell launcher so that VMware Horizon View Client was no longer the shell for the kiosk user but instead it was powershell with parameters that opened a separate script that looped checking for network connection and once it established that a connection had been made it looped opening VMware Horizon View Client and waiting so if it was closed it would automatically re-open.

The shell launcher script I used is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-shelllauncher).

The part I modified is:

```
$kiosk_app_path = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -windowstyle hidden -file C:\Scripts\DelayedShellLauncher.ps1"

# Set Powershell as the shell for "Cashier".
$ShellLauncherClass.SetCustomShell($Cashier_SID, $kiosk_app_path, ($null), ($null))
```

And here is the ps1 script I wrote:

```
do {
    Write-Host "Waiting for network connection..."
    } until(Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -Quiet -count 1)

while ($true) {
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Horizon View Client\vmware-view.exe" -wait
    }
```